# CTE joining the same table twice

Tags: sql-server

I have a table @MitoT with following code:

```
DECLARE @ResT UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID(), @ResC UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
DECLARE
    @MitoT TABLE (
        Pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        MitoResultID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        Position VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        Base VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

and populate it wits some data:

```
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '1', 'A');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '3', 'A');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '4', 'A');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '5', 'N');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResC, '1', 'A');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResC, '3', 'C');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResC, '5', '-');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '6', 'G');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResC, '6', 'T');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResT, '9', 'A');
INSERT INTO @MitoT VALUES (NEWID(), @ResC, '11', 'C');
```

so for any `Position` there can exist a row with `MitoResultID = @ResT` or with `MitoResultID = @ResC` or with both.
Now I try a CTE that returns me every `Position`, `BaseT` (which is `Base` `WHERE MitoResultID = @ResT`) and `BaseC` (which is `Base` `WHERE MitoResultID = @ResC`) for all cases:

```
WITH Compare (PositionT, PositionC, BaseT, BaseC) AS (
    SELECT t.Position, c.Position, t.Base, c.Base
        FROM @MitoT t
        FULL OUTER JOIN @MitoT c ON t.Position = c.Position
        WHERE (t.MitoResultID = @ResT AND c.MitoResultID = @ResC)
        OR (t.MitoResultID = @ResT AND c.MitoResultID IS NULL)
        OR (t.MitoResultID IS NULL AND c.MitoResultID = @ResC)
        )
SELECT * FROM Compare
```

But apparently I'm doing it wrong because it shows only those `Position` for which both `BaseT` and `BaseC` exist.
Please help me understand what is wrong.

UPDATE:
The result looks like:

| PositionT | PositionC | BaseT | BaseC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | N | - |
| 6 | 6 | G | T |
| 3 | 3 | A | C |
| 1 | 1 | A | A |

So i'm missing the rows for Positions like 4, 9, or 11 for which BaseT or BaseC is NULL

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: Sorry. Updated in the main post.

Comment: that is the result of the query or the result that you want ? Please explain explain what are you trying to achieve with that query

Comment: `MitoResultID` will never be null because - even for position `11` - you will get both left and right side. Solution might lie in prefiltering `@MitoT`  by `@ResT` and `@ResC` and then performing full outer join.

Comment: Long story short, would this be correct: `    SELECT t.Position, c.Position, t.Base, c.Base
        FROM (select * from @MitoT t where MitoResultID = @ResT) t
        FULL OUTER JOIN (select * from @MitoT c where MitoResultID = @ResC) c ON t.Position = c.Position`?

Comment: Thank you! This query works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Nikola Markovinović in his comment:

> `SELECT t.Position, c.Position, t.Base, c.Base FROM (select * from @MitoT t where MitoResultID = @ResT) t FULL OUTER JOIN (select * from @MitoT c where MitoResultID = @ResC) c ON t.Position = c.Position`

This works perfectly and CTE now looks like:

```
WITH Compare (PositionT, PositionC, BaseT, BaseC) AS (
    SELECT t.Position, c.Position, t.Base, c.Base 
        FROM (select * from @MitoT t where MitoResultID = @ResT) t 
        FULL OUTER JOIN (select * from @MitoT c where MitoResultID = @ResC) c 
        ON t.Position = c.Position
    )
SELECT * FROM Compare
```

with resulting table:

| PositionT | PositionC | BaseT | BaseC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | A |
| 3 | 3 | A | C |
| 5 | 5 | N | - |
| NULL | 11 | NULL | C |
| 6 | 6 | G | T |
| 9 | NULL | A | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | A | NULL |